# Act on all files in a folder in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

First, I don't really know AppleScript so this may be a stupid question but...

I am trying to act on all files in a specified folder with Photoshop (but since the script never gets to that part I don't think that it is relevant).  To do so I just copied a script which allegedly does more-or-less what I want from [Adobe's PS AppleScript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-applescript-ref.pdf) (pp. 242-243).  (I'll have to make a few changes but conceptually this is exactly what I want.)  But the script (cut-and-pasted unmodified from Adobe) doesn't work.  The problem appears to be with this line:

```
set fileList to (every file of anItem whose creator type is "8BIM") as alias list
```

Where "anItem" returned by "choose folder" is a folder and "creator type "8BIM" is Photoshop

When run, the script dies at that line with this error:

```
error "Can’t make every file of item 1 of
   {alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:PS Resave Test In:\"}
   whose «class fcrt» = \"8BIM\" into type alias list." number -1700
   from every file of item 1 of {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:
   PS Resave Test In:"} whose «class fcrt» = "8BIM" to «class alst»
```

I haven't been able to turn up anything searching for AppleScript error number -1700.

Can anyone maybe tell me what is happening so I can fix it? I can post the rest of the script if it would help, or just see the previous link to the Adobe reference.

Thanks!

----------------- Addendum 1 --------------------

adayzdone's answer below fixed this problem (thanks!), but the script is now failing at this line:

```
repeat with aFile in fileList
    tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of aFile
```

With this error:

```
error "Finder got an error: Can’t get alias
   \"Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:PS Resave Test In:Image 1.tif\"."
   number -1728 from alias 
   "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Desktop:PS Resave Test In:Image 1.tif"
```

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

----------------- Addendum 2 --------------------

As requested, here is the entire script:

```
-- Process all files in folders dropped on this script
-- (when saved as an applet)
-- Save each Adobe Photoshop CC file as a PDF file.

on run
    tell me to open {choose folder}
end run

on open droppedItems
    set destFolder to choose folder with prompt "Destination folder?"
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        tell application "Finder"
            -- Make sure each item processed by this script is a folder
            if class of item anItem is not folder then
                -- Not a folder, notify the user of the error
                display dialog "Please drop only folders on this script"
            else
                -- A folder, get the Adobe Photoshop CC files and process them
                set fileList to (every file of folder anItem whose creator type is "8BIM") as alias list
            end if
        end tell
        SaveFilesAsPDF(fileList, destFolder)
    end repeat
end open

-- fileList is a list of aliases to Photoshop files
-- destFolder is an alias to a folder where the PDF files are to be saved
on SaveFilesAsPDF(fileList, destFolder)
    set destPath to destFolder as string
    repeat with aFile in fileList
        tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of aFile
        set newFilePath to destPath & fileName & ".pdf"
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC"
            open aFile
            save current document in file newFilePath as Photoshop PDF ¬
                with options {class:PDF save options, PDF compatibility:PDF 15, preserve editing:true} ¬

            close current document saving no
        end tell
    end repeat
end SaveFilesAsPDF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set fileList to (every file of folder anItem whose creator type is "8BIM") as alias list
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that issue, but now the script is failing slightly after that line (why are you doing this to me Adobe???).  See the original question above for the code and error message (I can't figure out any way to put the code and error into a comment, so if I am doing this wrong by editing the question, sorry and please correct me).

Comment: Complete code posted in original question.  This has the change you advised but is otherwise cut-and-pasted from Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  Inferring from the fix you provided to my first probem, I added 'file' before 'aFile in 'tell application "Finder" to set fileName to name of aFile' and it worked.  I would never have gotten this working without your help and by all means, if you see fit to, please make any other suggestions you might have regarding the code.  I'll keep watching.